# How do these two lines differ in Java?

Tags: java

How do these two declarations differ in Java?

```
   class {

          int P = 1_000_000_007;
          P = 1000007;

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, one is just to read more easily, _ means nothing especial there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't legally define the same variable twice, but they define the same constant integer value

```
int P = 1_000_000_007;
System.out.println(P);
int P2 = 1000007;
System.out.println(P - P2);
```

output is (the second line is how much they *differ*)

```
1000000007
999000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are legal, though not in the same scope.

The value of `P` in the first case is 1000000007

The value of `P` in the second case is 1000007

See the difference?

The `_` characters are simply there to improve readability.  Like when you write one million as 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to put the character _ , it's just for a better readability, the only thing that u should remember that u shouldnt put it in the begin or in the end;

Greetings.